# Use of undefined constant curl - assumed 'curl'

Tags: php, curl

I feel like this may be a dupe, and I apologize if it is... but I cannot seem to figure out the answer for this problem. I am trying to use curl in PHP, and I received the following errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant curl - assumed 'curl' in /var/www/html/examples/example_curl_post.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to undefined function init() in /var/www/html/examples/example_curl_post.php on line 45
```

The code that causes that error is:

**Note** - I put it in a try block to catch the exception

```
try {
    $ch = curl.init();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

Before this I test to make sure curl is present.

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
} else {
    echo 'ok to proceed';
}
```

And `phpinfo()` shows that curl is enabled.

[image: phpinfo()]

Also the server is running on Lubuntu. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you wanted to use: `curl_init()` ? `.` and `_` aren't the same! change it to an underscore

Comment: `curl.init();` In PHP, a dot (`.`) is a concatenation operator.... you're trying to concatenate a constant called `curl` with the output from a function called `init()`.... because no constant called `curl` exists, PHP assumes that you meant to use `'curl'` as a string value, so dutifully does so, but not before issuing that notice message to tell you that it's doing so.... it then tries to execute the function `init()` to get the output from that to append to the string `'curl'` and fails because no function called `init()` exists

Comment: Note that neither notices nor fatal errors are Exceptions, so they can't be caught (unless you have a handler to convert notices to exceptions)

Comment: It always [helps to consult the manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Comment: Changing the `.` to a `_` fixed the issue. I am so used to Android and Java that I never saw the error in the code. Thanks a million.